# Getting full details from a link in the RSS data

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an RSS link in which there are rss links to pages such as AFL,Football, Basketball,Cricket etc. When I click that the RSS links are obtained. For example in case of AFL the rss link directs to the page

http://www.sportal.com.au/rss/australia/afl.xml

Here there are tags called "description" but there is only a part of description inside that tag. The full description is present inside the link present inside the tag "link". Here for example the link is

http://www.sportal.com.au/afl-news-display/pies-duo-set-to-feature-160240

How can I get these full description from the above link? I'm in such a urgency. Any help is appreciated.

//The Main Link is
//http://www.sportal.com.au/rss

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also faced  same problem but here one RSSFeed code . it will be Help to u i am sure,down load the code and pass the ur RSS Feed url simple...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your problem correctly then

For RSS parsing - https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

MWFeedParser is the best Open Source option for you !!

Comment: I have used the method you given. But still the problem exists. The problem is about the contents of parsing my friend. Inside the description tag there is no full description. Only part of it is given. But i need the full description. The full description is present inside the weblink inside the "link" tag. I need to get that data. How can i do that?

Comment: You probably need Data Scrapper as this API will return the DATA what is limited to RSS / FEED provides.